# UWP FlipView Images from URI (Web)

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, flipview

Actually, i have a list with image URIs. Inside a foreach-loop i create Image objects from these URIs like this:

```
foreach (Uri imageUri in uriList)
{
    BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageUri));
    Image image = new Image();
    image.source = bmi;

    flipView.Items.Add(image);
}
```

Now the problem is, if there are many Images (100-200), then the RAM usage is very high, when swiping fast through the FlipView. What i have seen also is, that every image, will be "cached" or something, so if i go back in the FlipView, no more internet traffic will be generated.

So my question is, is this the right way to do that, ore are there better ways to get a "Image Gallery" from Web Images?

Best Regards

Comment: I think the problem is possible not with `FlipView`, it takes time to convert uri to `Image` and add to `FlipView`, and it will convert all the items at the same time. Maybe you can try to convert images particle, for example convert and add to filpview each time 20 images, then show it. When user comes to the tenth item, continue to add next 20 items and so on?

Comment: I have tested it with 8 large images, the memory consumption is also huge.

Comment: I just tried to use ItemTemplate of `FlipView`, directly give the uri string as the source of Image control, it seems to work a little faseter, but with many huge images...I'm not sure this will be a good practice. I've no idea except particle showing now...Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flip view doesn't intended to be used to display large amount of items. You should use horizontal ListView instead.

First, you need to modify the style of the ListView to change HorizontalSnapPointsType property to MandatorySingle (so the image can be snap to correct position like the flip view). The cell's width should be equal to flipview's old width to ensure that

Comment: "flip view doesn't support virtualization" how can you be so sure ?!

Comment: I think he is correct, i have tested it and the Memory usage is still very high. But how can i use a ListView that has the same behaviour as the FlipView?

Comment: First, you need to modify the style of the ListView to change HorizontalSnapPointsType property to MandatorySingle (so the image can be snap to correct position like the flip view). The cell's width should be equal to flipview's old width to ensure that.

Sorry for the miss information, the default ItemsPanelTemplate of FlipView is VirtualizingStackPanel, which do support virtualization.

Comment: Ok this is working, thank you. But i can't figure out, how to make the item's width Stretch to the width of the Screen. I have tested multiple Parameters in the ListView and the ListViewItem Style, but the items are either less wide than, so i see already the next item, or they are wider. How can i achieve that?

Comment: You have to bind the width of the item to a static value (e.g: the width of the screen). Glad that its working for you, can you consider accept it as answer.

Comment: I did bound the width, but the Problem is, if i resize the window, the actual displayed Image does not fit and it will be cutted off, or part of the next Image is displayed. My Goal is to make it similar to the Microsoft photos app (resizing the Image, when resizing the Window). If thgis is working then sure, i will accept your post as answer.

Comment: when windows resize, you should notify the property changed, so your binding will update as the size changed. You can monitor the size change using SizeChanged event of the windows/frame. The Image control will resize the photo for you depend on the Stretch property.

Comment: So i Need to bind the Image Control inside my DataTemplate? Other Problem is, if i bind the Window.Current.Bound.Width, the Image is still wider than the available space.

Comment: first question: yes. You should use the RenderWidth of the ListView

Comment: RenderWidth Returns 0, as Long as no Content (ListViewItems) are set, so that's the Problem.

Comment: out it inside a grid, stretch it both vertical and horizontal, and use the RenderWidth of that grid ?

Comment: I have done this, but it Returns only a value, if at least one item is inside the ListView.

Comment: when do it get the value ? You should get it after elements are initialized.

Comment: Normally, after initialization the size of the controls should be available, yes. But the ListView gives me no size, until i add at least one item to it.

Comment: Did you try to get the size from the container of the ListView in this case ?

Comment: Ok it works now. Thank you very much for your great help, i marked your answer as solution.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/flipview), `FlipView` works best for a collection of that doesn't exceed 25 items (images).

The best thing you can do is to add `DataVirtualization to your FlipView, for example by doing :

```
<FlipView>
    <FlipView.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemsPanel>
</FlipView>
```

Concerning your images being "cached", that's normal, BitmapeImages cache your images by default.

Comment: It does not work, the Memory usage is still very high, when swiping fast through the items and the Memory usage remains high if i stop swiping through the items.